# Changing GPS location of Apple routers

Tags: iphone, wifi, gps

I have recently moved and have moved all my network gear with me.   Have approximately 4 wifi spots that I have re-set up in my new house.

To save battery apple devices also use location of known wifi hotspots to give locations.   My problem is that I suspect that this is a crowdsourced information gathering.   Sometimes my devices show themselves at my old house (while at new house).   I have waited for 2 weeks now, trying to use location services as much as possible to train apple about the new location of the wifi spots.

Is there anyway to force or speed up the change?   My alternative is to change the name of the hotspots, but do not want to go through the hassle of setting everything (range extenders, devices) again.

Comment: Been more than two weeks at the new location now and locations in maps, notification etc and devices that connect to this Wifi still jump back to old now incorrect location.   Does not seem like issue will be resolving itself without intervention

Comment: what's the distance between the old and the new location?

Comment: 8km by road, probably 3km as crow flies

Comment: thinking a bit further... new location is probably about the same distance from big cell phone tower, just on the other side of it.   Might contribute to its confusion

Comment: i just wanted to ask this. it's probably also the same inet-provider and cable/dsl central switch (or whatever you use)?

Comment: no internet provider changed, but the router is the same.   This router is connected by LAN cable to more Apple Airport devices in bridge mode that rebroadcast the network using the same SSID.

Answer (score 2):

There's a company called SkyHook that sells a wifi-based geolocation product to many companies, but not sure if Apple is one of them. It was a couple of years ago though.

You can ask them to update their database here: http://www.skyhookwireless.com/submit-access-point. If Apple is doing their own geolocation services now, you're likely out of luck.

ETA: changing your (E)SSID probably won't do anything; the location services are more likely to use the BSSID, which is the wireless MAC address of the equipment.

Comment: Yes I remember that they used them.   As far as I can see Apple still uses them.   Have updated the location of my main Router (both frequency bands)   there is however a one week waiting period.   Will see if this resolves it and give feedback here.

Comment: I don't have the Wireless Mac addresses of my airports that repeat the signal with me at moment, will submit them to skyhook as well this evening when i can check

Comment: Do you have any Apple devices with GPS? Or is it just laptops and iPods? Regardless of any updates you submit, once Apple's servers can "see" your router at a new GPS location it should be updated. Maybe have some friends with iPhones over for coffee?

Comment: got at least 3 iphones frequenting the network.  3 different Ipads also on network, so there should be plenty GPS data to feed back to apple to update devices

Answer (score 0):

im not sure this will help, my gut says it might, but under wireless settings in your iOS device, forget network then re connect, (note you need to reenter password and SSID)

Comment: have tried that few times no luck